# Variable no me aumenta y no veo el fallo

Tags: java

Buenas, estoy comparando un vector con cada una de las filas de una matriz. He creado una variable para que me indique cuando ha llegado al final del vector para que no siga comparando. Dicha variable(llamada coincidencia) la aumento cada vez que encuentro una coincidencia pero no me aumenta su valor y no entiendo por que. Al no aumentar, no me entra en el if que la compara con la longitud del vector y me sigue comparando. ¿Alguien me podría indicar mi error o darme alguna pista sobre la solución?. Gracias de antemano.

```
    int[][] matriz = {{2, 4, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 5}, {1, 8, 9}};
    int[] vector = {2, 4, 5};

    int coincidencia = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {

            if (vector.length  <= matriz[i].length ) {

                for (int k = 0; k < vector.length; k++) {

                    if (vector[k] == matriz[i][j]) {
                        System.out.println("Coincidencia en " + "[" + i + "]" + "[" + j + "]");
                        coincidencia++;
                        System.out.println(coincidencia);
                    } else {
                        coincidencia = 0;
                    }
                }
                if(coincidencia == vector.length) {
                    break;
                }
            } else{
                break;
            }
         }
    }
```

Comment: cada vez que coincidencia no entra en el if, lo regresas al valor de 0, no se supone que en el else no haría nada? así se perderían las coincidencias cada que entre al else.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu comentario me ha ayudado a solucionar el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otra vez tienes un problema de logica en tu algoritmo...

estas buscando coincidencias, y lo estas haciendo mal...

analicemos tu codigo (otra vez, ya lo hicimos varias veces):

```
for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
//recorres las filas de la matriz
    for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
    //recorres las columnas de la matriz
        if (vector.length  <= matriz[i].length ) {
        //compruebas si el vector es menor que la fila de la matriz, bien
            for (int k = 0; k < vector.length; k++) {
            //recorres el vector....
                if (vector[k] == matriz[i][j]) {
                //comparas el vector, contra la posicion de la matriz.. pero todo el vector?
                //contra la misma posicion de la matriz? entonces aqui esta el error.
```

Tu solucion deberia ser algo asi:

```
int[][] matriz = {{2, 4, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 5}, {1, 8, 9}};
int[] vector = {2, 4, 5};

int punteroalvector = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) 
{
   for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) 
   {
       if (vector[punteroalvector] == matriz[i][j]) 
       {
           punteroalvector++;
           if (punteroalvector == vector.length)
           {
              System.out.println("encontre");
              System.out.println("i: " + i + " j desde: " + (j-punteroalvector) + " j hasta: " + j);
              break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            punteroalvector = 0;
        }
    }
    if (punteroalvector == vector.length)
    {

         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responderme en diversas ocasiones. Como dices, tengo diversos errores de lógica a la hora de estructurar el código debido a que soy nuevo en esto aún. Como ya dije, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, el problema de por qué no te está funcionando:

Si te fijas tienes 3 `for` anidados, y donde realizas la comparación es en el más interior, o sea, estás comparando cada uno de los elementos del vector con el primero de los elementos de la fila de la matriz. Luego todos los elementos del vector con el segundo de la fila de la matriz, y así sucesivamente. El problema es que sobra un iterador. Debes iterar por la i-ésima fila comparando los j-ésimos elementos del vector y de ese fila.

Pienso que este código debe solucionar el problema.

```
int[][] matriz = {{2, 4, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 5}, {1, 8, 9}};
int[] vector = {2, 4, 5};

int coincidencia = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {

    if (vector.length  == matriz[i].length ) {
        //si en esta fila no hay la misma cantidad de elementos, pasa a la siguiente

        coincidencia = 0;   //reset de la variable que actua como contador
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {

            if (vector[j] == matriz[i][j]) {
                System.out.println("Coincidencia en " + "[" + i + "]" + "[" + j + "]");
                coincidencia++;
                System.out.println(coincidencia);
            } else {
                //si uno fallo, ya no es el vector lo que hay en esta fila
                break;
            }

        }

        if (coincidencia == vector.length) {
            //encontramos el vector!
            break;
        }   
    }   
}
```

El otro problema que veo en el código que estás usando es que tienes el `if` anidado dentro del segundo `for`, de manera que se hacen comparaciones del tamaño de la fila que son innecesarias.

Y por último, la condición del `if` en realidad es que la fila de la matriz sea exactamente igual al tamaño del vector que buscas. Esto acelerará y simplificará mucho el código.

Espero haber ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

¿Disculpa, con coincidencia te refieres a que en la matriz se encuentre el vector cierto?, si ese es el caso pues es mucho mas fácil de esta manera:

```
int[][] matriz = {{2, 4, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 5}, {1, 8, 9}};
    int[] vector = {2, 4, 6};

    int coincidencias = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        if(Arrays.equals(matriz[i], vector)){//Claramente Arrays.equals compara 2 arreglos de cualquier tipo para ver si sus elementos son los mismos.
            coincidencias++;
        }
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Coincidencias: "+coincidencias);
```

Comment: Revisar [answer], recuerda que las respuestas no se usan para pedir aclaración sobre la pregunta, para eso puedes realizar comentarios.